# SSRS 2008 R2 Charts - Hide WhiteSpace for a series value that returns 0

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to remove the whitespace for the bars (or series) that do not return a value.

The chart I posted returns no values for April, May, June, Sept., Nov. or December and as result there is a gap for each of those months. I'd like to hide these gaps and have the existing bars display side by side.

I've tried adding a conditional statement to each month under the Visibility property (under Series Properties) and had no luck. Example:

```
=iif(isnothing(sum(fields!jan.Value)), true, false)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: SSRS 2008 R2 Column Chart][1]
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrSXN.png

Comment: Can I ask why exactly you want to hide the months with no data? When you are displaying time series data like this, only displaying months with data might be misleading to user, who might be expecting all months to be shown?

Comment: That said, one option is to modify the query in your dataset so that no rows are returned for months with no values.

Comment: My reason is that I sometimes have 8+ category groups, right now you're only seeing one, and when this occurs the width of the bars are pencil thin. I figured if I could eliminate these gaps the width of each individual bar would then increase. Anyhow, I'll talk to my end user before making any changes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you filter out the data at the chart level and/or the category group level. Then it wouldn't get included in the rendering of the chart. You can filter on Sum(field) = 0 or whatever the appropriate aggregation is that you are using.